# Bulkify Scheduled Apex Class

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

I have just created my first scheduled Apex Class and need a bit of help with the "bulkification" process.

**Objective:**

My scheduled Apex Class is designed to update a datetime field on each Contact on a recurring daily basis.

**Issue:**

After deploying to production (where I have over 200,000 contacts), I received a `System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001` exception. I understand that I need to use Batch Apex to comply with SFDC's resource limitations.

I am very new to Apex development and am trying to wrap my head around how to "bulkify" my code.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**Code:**

```
global class ScheduledRecurringUpdateOnContact implements Schedulable {
List<Contact> allRec = new List<Contact>();
List<Contact> toUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    global void  execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        allRec = [select id, Scheduled_Recurring_Update__c from Contact];
        for(Contact ge: allRec){
            ge.Scheduled_Recurring_Update__c = datetime.now();
            toUpdate.add(ge);
        }
        update toUpdate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to jump over from a scheduled class to a batch class. The easiest way to do so is to add the Batchable interface atop what you already have:

```
global class ScheduledRecurringUpdateOnContact implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    global void  execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([select id from Contact]);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Contact[] allRec) {
        for(Contact ge: allRec){
            ge.Scheduled_Recurring_Update__c = datetime.now();
        }
        update allRec;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    }
}
```

Note that we can omit the field you're updating because we don't need to access the original value. This optimizes the start method slightly. Also, we can update records that were in the original query result without adding to a separate list, which saves some CPU time and memory use.

Comment: Thanks for your help @sfdcfox! I'm receiving the following error: `Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: Batchable at line 1`. Is this because I need to implement `Database.Batchable` on line 1? If not, any ideas what may be going wrong?

Comment: @Brandon Yes, that was a typo on my part, it should have been `Database.Batchable`. I've updated my answer with this correction.

Comment: Thank you for helping with this, sfdcfox! Your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

So what you would essentially need to do is to create a Batch class which would work on all of the Contacts from your Query in batches. You will need to learn more about how batch classes work in order to implement it. Here is some [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) and here is a trailhead exercise to help you learn - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/asynchronous_apex/units/async_apex_batch

You could implement the Batchable interface in the same class as above and call the Batch from the execute method of your Schedular in order to keep everything in the same class.